# Transform not working after publish

Tags: identity-server

I have created a transform file In Visual studio by right click on the config file and selected the Add Transform option instead of `SlowCheetah`.

[image]

After selection its creating the transformation file into the project for QA-CM, QA-CD, an etc environment defined into the configuration manager as below:

[image]

I am going to change the `SITECORE_ENVIRONMENT` value using the transformation file. `Web.Config` file has the below code:

[image]

And I have added the below code into the `Web.QA-CD.config` to update value:

[image]

When I right-click on `Web.QA-CD.config` file and select the `Preview Transform` option it shows me the correct result as below:

[image]

But if I publish the project in the `QA-CD` environment configuration then it does not reflect the updated value on the server `web.config`.

> **Sitecore**: 9.3.0,
> **Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017**
> Version 15.9.19

Comment: Are you publishing to your Identity Server?

Comment: Yes @MarkCassidy

Comment: what the result on your Identity website folder? That value contains there?